# Upgrade legacy signing key to new signing key got issue about secure shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, apk, keystore

I changed legacy signing key to new signing key of Android application on Google play console.

On current app user use app version 1 (use legacy signing key)
then they update application to app version 2 (I did not know it use legacy signing key or new signing key)

But I got issue that can not get shared preference (I set it with private mode)

Do you have information or some article that explain this issue?

```
private val preferences: SharedPreferences

this.preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Comment: what kind of problem you faced now?